# What does "to play valet" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I've seen all available definitions of "valet" but none of them makes sense.

Comment: You need to give us the context in which *play valet* occurred.

Comment: With the sense ***valet = manservant***, you could reasonably use it in *Don't call me Jeeves! I won't play valet to your Bertie Wooster!*

Comment: Might refer to the video game, but as StoneyB says without context we might as well play charades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the item of confusion may be the phrase "**to play [at] {something}**" which is an idiom meaning "**to pretend to be {something}**".

If I was going to drive you around, I might say I'm "**playing chauffeur**". I'm not really a chauffeur (a person paid to drive you around); I'm just playing at it.

So if someone said they were **playing valet**, it might mean they were going to park your car for you (but they are not really a valet) or maybe they're tying your tie for you or straightening up your suit -- they aren't your real personal valet (manservant), but they are playing one for now.